# Are IEC 60601-1-2 medical emc and FCC compatible?

Tags: fcc

I must comply with the medical EMC standard IEC 60601-1-2 but wireless modules do not come certified to this standard.

For example, telit fn980 is certified to FCC, RED, etc.

Are FCC certified devices automatically compatible with 60601-1-2?

Comment: The simple answer is No, FCC certification of an included radio module does not fulfill the EMC immunity and emission requirements for your medical device. I recommend you get consulting help.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what additional cispr 11 regulations apply to emissions over normal FCC standards?